# Java string split on multiple delimiters for boolean expression

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I want to split a string in Java that represents a boolean expression. The string is of the form:

```
key <operator> value
```

where operator can be "==", "!=", ">", "<"

For example:
Input1: `a==2` output `["a", "2"]`
Input2: `b!=3` output `["b", "3"]`

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: "a==2".split("==|!=|>|<") http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
String[] arr;                       //create a string array to reference later
if (Input1.contains("=="))          //check string for measure
     arr = String.split("==");      //split string at those points
else if (Input1.contains("!="))     //a==2 -> ["a", "2"]
     arr = String.split("!=");
else if (Input1.contains(">"))
     arr = String.split(">");
else if (Input1.contains("<"))
     arr = String.split("<");
```

or:

```
String arr[] = Input1.split("!=|>|<|==");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the regex part, list all of your signs separated by a single OR sign (|).